# Ninject Portable in Xamarin results in NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ninject

When I use Portable.Ninject in a Xamarin.Forms app, instantiating the StandardKernel always results in a `NotImplementedException`.

I can consistently replicate the problem as follows:

- Create Xamarin.Forms application (in VS2017: Cross Platform App (Xamarin))
- Configure it to use **PCL**
- I'm only interested in Android and for the sake of brevity, I removed all other platform projects.
- Add NuGet Package **Portable.Ninject** to the PCL and Android platforms

Then, in App.xaml.cs I simply try the following:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //ommitting NinjectModules for brevity
    var kernel = new Ninject.StandardKernel(); //exception is thrown here
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainView());
}
```

What am I missing here?

Currently I'm using Portable.Ninject version 3.3.1.
I also tried the **XLabs.IoC.Ninject** package (which also uses Portable.Ninject) and got the same result.

Comment: There's an existing sample here on this item: https://github.com/RobGibbens/Xamarin.IoC/tree/master/NinjectDemo

Comment: Thanks for the link. Very helpful repository there. 
I checked the sample and it wasn't doing anything else than what was going in my app. It ran perfectly, while my project didn't.
I checked for differences in the csproj files and nothing special came up.
Finally, I did a CLEAN on my projects, built it, and voila! Magic. Somehow a faulty Ninject version must have crept into my bin folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who experience the same problem:

*tldr; **clean** you projects, and rebuild.*

Explanation: At first I had only added Ninject to my PCL, and had forgotten to add it to the Android project. Although I added the Ninject library to the Android project soon afterwards, it would still result in the exception being thrown.

The solution was to clean the projects and rebuild them. Sometimes it's just that easy!